Intuitive reason for periods of 2 and 8 in Bott periodicity?
Is there a reasonably simple explanation for why Bott periodicity for $U$ and $O$ have periods 2 and 8, respectively? For example, in the $h$-cobordism theorem the requirement that $n \geq 5$ has the intuitive explanation that you need enough space in the ambient manifold to use the Whitney trick to push a disk off of itself, which takes ambient dimension at least $2\cdot 2 + 1$. Is there a similar idea or fact that might convey to a (relative) layperson why the numbers 2 and 8 come up in Bott periodicity?

I've always thought about these as coming from the "Bott periodicity" in the classification of real and complex Clifford algebras - which I tend to think as much less surprising as it just corresponds to the fact that $Cl_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $Cl_8(\mathbb{R})$ happen to be isomorphic to matrix algebras (which I'm happy to attribute to chances as there isn't that many option for what these algebras can be) - I'm not sure this answer your question, but maybe you'll want to comment on what sort of thing in that line of thought you would consider an answer to your question.

@Simon: I was under the impression that this does not actually give a proof of Bott periodicity, and one has to use Bott periodicity itself to relate Clifford algebras to Bott periodicity?

@QiaochuYuan I might be wrong on this, but I am fairly sure I have seen proof of Bott periodicity relying on Clifford algebra in the context of the K-theory of C* algebra (which immediately imply bott periodicity in topology K-theory, and then the periodicity of these spectrum), but that was a long time ago, so I'd have to do some research to remind myself how this works...

@SimonHenry Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro write in "Clifford Modules" (1963) that "one should look for a proof of the periodicity theorem using Clifford algebras. Since this paper was written a proof on these lines has in fact been found by R. Wood. See also the proof given in: J. Milnor, Morse Theory". Not sure if the proof made it into any of Wood's papers, but Milnor's is in section IV.24 of the Morse theory book.

@SimonHenry Thanks! To be fair my question is somewhat vague; I was mainly wondering if there was some semi-magical numerical fact that explains the 8 in particular, and your answer helps a lot.

Here is one source of intuition for the 8-fold and 2-fold Bott periodicities, from the physics of topological states of matter. See this online lecture.
In physics, Bott periodicity governs the classification of the fundamental symmetries of free electrons: the anti-unitary symmetries ${\cal T}_\pm$ (time-reversal symmetry) and ${\cal P}_\pm$ (particle-hole symmetry), and the unitary symmetry ${\cal C}={\cal PT}$ (chiral symmetry). The subscript $\pm$ distinguishes whether the anti-unitary symmetry squares to $+1$ or $-1$.
There are 8 symmetry classes with at least one anti-unitary symmetry: $${\cal P}_+;\;\;{\cal P}_-;\;\;{\cal T}_+;\;\;{\cal T}_-;$$
$${\cal P}_+,{\cal T}_+;\;\;{\cal P}_+,{\cal T}_-;\;\;{\cal P}_-,{\cal T}_+;\;\;{\cal P}_-,{\cal T}_-;$$
There are 2 symmetry classes with no anti-unitary symmetries, one with and one without chiral symmetry:
$${\cal C};\;\;\times;$$
A gapped system on a $d$-dimensional torus can be raised to dimension $d+1$ by adding one momentum component, in such a way that the gap does not close on the torus. This operation transforms the symmetry class in a way that reflects the Bott periodicity, as indicated in the diagram below (the "Bott clock").

The arrows indicate the change of symmetry if dimension $d$ is raised to dimension $d+1$. Without any anti-unitary symmetry the cycle has period 2, with at least one anti-unitary symmetry the cycle has period 8.

Thanks for the answer! I'm not a physicist but it's very interesting that there's a physical interpretation of Bott periodicity.
